# Why find and replace using cscope is producing tcache2 error?

Tags: linux, text

I am trying to change a given string in a large project to another string using `cscope` `[Change this text string:]`. When it prompts to select the instances, I press `ctrl + a` to select all and then `ctrl + d` to confirm and exit. Then it prompts me to press **`RETURN`**. So I press *Enter* and then it crashes producing the error : `double free error tcache2. Abort()`.

I couldn't find the problem and whether I am doing anything wrong.